# Android data disappeared

Tags: data-recovery

I got an Android Tablet (Samsung SM-T800). I recently went into Download Mode (holding down some keys during startup), just to check if options for factory reset are available. I canceled out of Download Mode and booted up normal. Now all my photos and documents are gone. Only 2 of over 100 pics are still there. All the apps and settings are still there. I didn't do a factory reset, so I don't understand why my photos are gone. If I plug the tablet into my PC, the space that was once used by the photos is still occupied. I guess, they are still there, but for some reason they are invisible. I tried some data recovery apps from the Google Play Store to no avail. The data is stored on the internal SD card. Can anybody tell me, how I could get my data back?

Comment: Maybe the files are still there but the media database is corrupt (a lot of apps just show the media database to locate files)? Use a file manager app to check what is really left in the file-system.

Comment: Are there any file managers you would recommend me to use, that don`t use the media database? I don`t wanna install too many apps from the Google Play Store in fear of overwriting my files.

Comment: Any file manager will do all file manager I know use the file-system and not the media database as information source.